# Why is this http-server doing this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, localhost

I'm new to Node and I'm trying to run a local server.

I followed this simple steps: [Setup a simple Node server](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/06/22/nodejs-setup-simple-http-server-local-web-server).

I move to the folder I have the ***index.html*** file:

[image]

I run ***http-server*** then I browse to ***http://localhost:8080/*** and this is what I get:

[image]

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It's clearly showing you that the server is running by showing a directory index. The question is, do you expect something else, and if so, what? You have to show the code you have, the routes, and what should be served up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one has caught me out a couple of times too - [if you have a `./public` folder, the `http-server` library defaults to serving that rather than `./`.](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server#usage-1) Kind of a silly default, in my opinion, but oh well!

You can get around this by explicitly stating the path when you start the server:

```
http-server ./
```